# What does the phrase "mettre l'eau à la bouche" mean ?

Tags: sens, expressions

What does the phrase “*mettre l'eau à la bouche*” mean ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

"mettre l'eau à la bouche"

Ça signifie : tenter, faire envie, intéresser, faire désirer, stimuler le désir, donner envie de qqchose (manger, boire, consommer, sexualité, etc.)

Exemple :

1. *Le déjeuner est une tradition locale, avec une grande variété de plats pour vous mettre l'eau à la bouche.*
   En anglais : *Lunch here is a local tradition, with a huge array of cuisines to tempt you.*
2. *Voici quelques idées pour vous mettre l'eau à la bouche !*
   En anglais : *Here are some ideas to whet your adventurous spirit!*

Answer (score 2):

well, it looks like there's a litteral english equivalent for that one:

> to be mouth-watering

or

> to whet one's appetite

(basically those are from my google-fu)